# How to implicitly load only signed DLL s

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have an application which is linked with set of dll files. I am loading the DLL s implicitly without going through insecure LoadLibrary() calls. I am thinking of signing the DLL s with a certificate file to avoid DLL hijacking. I have a doubt that how can implicit linking checks whether my DLL s are signed or not.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a manifest dependency using the [MANIFESTDEPENDENCY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/build/reference/manifestdependency-specify-manifest-dependencies?view=vs-2017) linker option and set [`publicKeyToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/SbsCs/publisher-configuration-files) to the key used to sign the dlls.

E.g. something like:

```
/manifestdependancy:type='win32' name='mydll' language='*' publicKeyToken='1234567890ABCDEF0'
```

Windows will then refuse to load your application unless the dll matching the above conditions is present.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I tried to add this to my project and it is throwing linker error while compiling the dependent project..It is looking for the object file specified in the name field.If I link the object file which is in the build directory of the linked library.It is compiling and the application still fails to start. Am I missing something

Comment: The name field should be set to the name of the dll(without the .dll extension)